# AFNetworking SSL pinning doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking-3

Im trying to make SSL pinning in my app. After all guides i got this:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
policy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
NSData *localCertificate = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my" ofType:@"cer"]];
policy.pinnedCertificates = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:localCertificate, nil];
self.securityPolicy = policy;
```

"self" is subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager.

I tested this on two servers.
The first server has my.cer, and when i make some request, the method `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler` of `AFURLSessionManager` is called. Then certificates compares and everything is okay.

Second server have no my.cer. When i make requests `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler` of `AFURLSessionManager` doesn't calls and сertificate checking does not happening, but i can make requests and get responses.

Is there a way to cancel request if I did not receive a certificate from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process of searching for at least some information, I came across a discussion and found that NSAllowsArbitraryLoads bit in my info.plist was causing it.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Deleting this helped me.
Hope, this will help anyone else.